# Gallery Swipe with Sounds

Tags: java, android, gallery, swipe, audio

I've been searching for code for gallery with sounds (Swipe) then this is the last I did. When I open the activity the first photo played it sounds but when I swipe it for the next picture, it won't.

```
    public class alphagal extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.numgal);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private int[] mImages = new int[] {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.bb};
        private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.capture,R.raw.capture2};

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = alphagal.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            if(position>=1){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(alphagal.this, mAudio[position-1]);
                mp.start();
            }
            return imageView;
        }
        OnPageChangeListener player = new OnPageChangeListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0)
            {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(alphagal.this, mAudio[arg0]);
                mp.start();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0)
            {
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of OnPageChangeListener because on each swipe instantiateItem() is called.I modified your code little bit ,it working .please check .One more thing you have to overwrite the onbackpress() to stop the media player otherwise it continue to play if you exit the application.

```
    public class alphagal extends Activity {

     MediaPlayer mp;
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.numgal);
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private int[] mImages = new int[] {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.bb};
        private int[] mAudio = new int[]{R.raw.capture,R.raw.capture2};

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mImages.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((ImageView) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Context context = alphagal.this;
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
            ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
            if (position >= 1) {
                //if you have already the instance of media player
                if (mp != null) {
                    if (mp.isPlaying())
                        mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();

                    try {
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources()
                                .openRawResourceFd(mAudio[position - 1]);
                        if (afd == null)
                            return null;
                        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),
                                afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        afd.close();
                        mp.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    // player is null
                    // it will create new MediaPlayer instance, setDataSource
                    // and call prepare
                    mp = MediaPlayer
                            .create(alphagal.this, mAudio[position - 1]);
                }
                mp.start();
            }
            return imageView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //need to handle otherwise if you exit from the app media 
        //player continue to play
        if (null != mp) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: The 2nd pic doesn't play sounds.

Comment: have you check both file are mp3? or try with some new files because i have checked the code it working properly.